# Query for find Posts don't have custom fields

Tags: sql, wordpress

I write this Query to find posts that have custom field 'language' that value of it is 'English' OR Posts don't have custom field 'language' at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id  
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'language' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value like '%English%' OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta Where wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'language' ))
```

But, it return only posts that have custom field 'language' and value of it is 'English'

Please help me

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: @JW my all posts have custom fields but I post_types are different that have different custom fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be careful with parentheses in where condition -

try the below query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts , wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id  
AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'language' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value like '%English%' ) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta Where wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'language' ))
```

and one more thing you need one condition on IDs in exist subquery like below  -

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts , wp_postmeta 
    WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id  
    AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'language' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value like '%English%' ) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1 Where wp_postmeta1.meta_key = 'language' and wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_postmeta.post_id ))
```

Comment: How is your query different from OPs? Parentheses around `AND` are not needed.

Comment: @Ehsan you should have ID comparision condition in your subquery.
I have added into posted query .. try with that ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id  
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'language' AND 
     wp_postmeta.meta_value like '%English%')
OR (wp_postmeta.meta_key != 'language');  --Not sure if you want (!= language) or null. Change as required.
```